# (VERI-1322) prefix of assignment pattern must be a data type

Tags: variable-assignment, system-verilog

Here is a snippet from my code;

```
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin : output_assigment // left side should only be "_q"
    if(reset_n == 1'b0 || clear == 1'b1) out_signal_q <= {8'{!(REPORT_POL)}};
```

But i see this error:   (VERI-1322) prefix of assignment pattern must be a data type

How can this be corrected for the assignment "out_signal_q <= {8'{!(REPORT_POL)}}"
Can you please help ?
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always helps to show declarations of all signals involved in the expression. I have to assume that `REPORT_POL` is a single bit and you want it replicated 8 times to assigned to `out_signal_q`. In that case you want to remove the `'` and just write

```
out_signal_q <= {8{!REPORT_POL}};
```